# How is it possible to overlay images with a relative position?

Tags: html, css, z-index, css-position

I need to keep my images relative so they are in the right place in the div but I can't get the z-index to work! This is my html code:

```
<img src="images/banners/banner1.jpg" class="banner" /><br /><br />
<div id="social_cont">
    <div id="social">
    Hello!!
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my css:

```
.banner {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

#social_cont {
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
}
#social {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

At the moment all I get is the banner and then the text centered underneath it, why is this?

Comment: Because you have not moved the elements at all from their default-render positions. What do you expect `position: relative` and `z-index` to do?

Comment: Well I assumed that if they were above the image they would go to the top of the page! What would the correct code to use to move it up?

Comment: When using `top: -50px;` nothing happens

Comment: @Yesterday Please explain what you desire from the markup you provided.

Comment: The text to be on top of the image, so I tried moving it up so that it would overlay it 50 pixels up from it's current position

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2EDnj/ is one of may ways to have the text above the banner. I tried to use as much of your code as possible.

Comment: I just worked out how to do this as you posted this comment but I can't center it now, how would I be able to center the text on the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused about what `z-index` does. First of all, let me refer you to the current version of a very old but very good [CSS reference](http://www.westciv.com/style_master/house/tutorials/quick/positioning/index.html) from which I learned myself.

What `z-index` does is decide which element will be "on top" *if multiple elements are forced to occupy the same space in the render*. By default (unless you use CSS to change the position of some elements), this can never happen.

There is not enough information in your question to give you a good answer at this time. If you just want the `div`s above the banner, why don't you simply move them around in the HTML to appear before the banner?

**Update**:

So it seems you want the banner to act as *background* for your text. That's what CSS `background` is for:

```
<div id="social_cont" style="background: url(images/banners/banner1.jpg)">
    <div id="social">Hello!!</div>
</div>
```

You can use the various CSS [background-related properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html) to tweak the alignments and such as you wish.

Comment: No, I would like the text on top of the banner

Comment: Hmm... I never thought of that, I will see how it looks!

Comment: This does work but when using the margin top and bottom like this:
   `margin-top: 90px;
   margin-bottom: 90px;`
It positions it in the correct place but it only uses the image to the height of the text.

Comment: @Yesterday: Padding is not the most appropriate here. Just directly specify a `height` for `#social_cont`.

Answer (score 1):

An element with `position:relative` keeps it's position and also still affects all other following elements. That's the reason why your div won't overlap the image by just using `z-index`. You'll still need to position the div element with, for example: `top:-100px` where the amount would be the height of the image.
The best way is to use Jons answer. Set your image as a background image for the element.

Answer (score 0):

@Jon is correct. I believe you want something like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/2EDnj/4/